# How to Enable Button if there is Item in ComboBox in pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

[image: The problem in image]
[image]

Hi, in this image i want to enable start button when USB name appear in combo-Box and if the name does not appear the button should disabled automatically, Here is My Code.

```
def x(self):
      if (self.comboBox_3.currentIndex() == -1):
          self.pushButton_5.setEnabled(False)
      else:
          self.pushButton_5.setEnabled(True)
```

Comment: How is `x()` called? You need to set up the button (or some listener) to watch the value of  the comboBox and how it changes and respond to that event.

Comment: @AndrewPaxson x() called in  __init__ Function when QMainWindow open it's run

Comment: You have to connect the combox's changes to this function. http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/eventssignals/

Comment: @AndrewPaxson Can you explain with code please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the currentIndexChanged signal to evaluate that logic:

```
    # __init__ method
    # ...
    self.comboBox_3.currentIndexChanged[int].connect(self.on_currentIndexChanged)

def on_currentIndexChanged(self, index):
    self.pushButton_5.setEnabled(index != -1)
```